# Deriving probability of hitting stop loss given annual return and Sharpe

Tags: brownian-motion, simulations, sharpe-ratio, maximum-drawdown, stop-loss

Suppose I have a strategy with a mean return and defined Sharpe. Given a preset stop loss, I want to calculate the probability of the stop being hit.

In the example below I use the following parameters,

- Sharpe ratio = 1.3
- Annual return = 10%
- Stop loss threshold = 5%

I *think* the following code is bug-free. But the results are highly counterintuitive to me.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


annual_return = 0.1
num_days = 252
sharpe = 1.3
annual_vol = annual_return / sharpe
daily_return = annual_return / num_days
daily_vol = annual_vol / np.sqrt(252)
num_sims = np.arange(10000)
np.random.seed(42)
drawdown_vector = list()
for ns in num_sims:
    random_walk = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(daily_return, daily_vol, num_days))
    cumul_return = pd.DataFrame(random_walk.cumsum())
    hwm = pd.DataFrame(cumul_return.cummax())
    drawdown = pd.DataFrame(cumul_return - hwm)
    max_drawdown = pd.DataFrame(drawdown.cummin())
    drawdown_vector.append(max_drawdown.iloc[-1])
threshold = -0.05
count_stops = 0
for dv in drawdown_vector:
    if dv[0] < threshold:
        count_stops +=1
print('prob of hitting 5% stop: ', count_stops / len(num_sims))
```

When running the above code, the result I get is that for a strategy of Sharpe 1.3 (which I think is pretty good), the probability of hitting a 5% stop loss assuming a 10% return is **59.76%**.

This seems too high to me, but perhaps my intuition is wrong. Or the code is?

Any insights would be appreciated.